# Running a saved MS Access macro in python: ERROR

Tags: python, ms-access, win32com

I am trying to run a saved MS Access macro using python. However, upon executing my code, i get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(strDbName)
  File "<COMObject Access.Application>", line 3, in OpenCurrentDatabase
  File "C:\Users\ash\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 287, in _ApplyTypes_
    result = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(*(dispid, LCID, wFlags, retType, argTypes) + args)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, "Microsoft Access can't open the database because it is missing, or opened exclusively by another user, or it is not an ADP file.", None, -1, -2146820422), None)
```

- the file exists.
- no password protection
  -i have even suppressed all warnings at the beginning of the query(SetWarnings: No)

  ```py
  import win32api,time
  from win32com.client import Dispatch

  strDbName = 'testing.accdb'
  objAccess = Dispatch("Access.Application")
  objAccess.Visible = False
  objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(strDbName)
  objDB = objAccess.CurrentDb()
  objAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro('test')
  objAccess.Application.Quit()
  ```

Comment: try to use full path for file name

Comment: oh. THAT WORKED. thank you! my python file and the access db were both is the same folder which is why i didnt specify the full path. didnt think that could've been the problem. thanks again!