# Python script to open MS Access and Run Macro, cannot find the file error

Tags: python, ms-access, win32com

I have the same exact problem than

[Running a saved MS Access macro in python: ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57374277/running-a-saved-ms-access-macro-in-python-error)

I' using the exact same code but with my Access File and Macro names, using the complete path as suggested but getting the same error.

```
import win32api,time
from win32com.client import Dispatch

strDbName = '\\server\folder\file.accdb'
objAccess = Dispatch("Access.Application")
objAccess.Visible = False
objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(strDbName)
objDB = objAccess.CurrentDb()
objAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro('test')
objAccess.Application.Quit()
```

My access is stored in a network path that I'm writing like this

```
strDbName = '\\server\folder\file.accdb'
```

I have also tried

```
strDbName = 'r\\server\folder\file.accdb'
```

but I always get the error "Microsoft Access can't open the database because it is missing, or opened exclusively by another user, or it is not an ADP file."

any clue?

Comment: Do you have to use Python? I just downloaded. Can't get past error about "No module named 'win32api'" and the fix seems complicated. I know I can do this with VBScript.

Comment: You put the `r` inside the quoted string.  Try this way instead: `strDbName = r'\\server\folder\file.accdb'` More info: [python raw string](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+raw+string)

Comment: @HansUp It actually worked!!, I cannot believe it was that simple... thanks!!!